# boost spirit rule with phoenix bind to structure - compile failure

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I want to parse the following string: `id=1;entry1=[A,B,D];entry2=[bla,blubb];factor=[1,5]!`

My Parser:

```
struct Entry
{
  uint32_t id;
  std::vector< std::string > entry1;
  std::vector< std::string > entry2;

  bool useFactor;
  std::pair<int, int> factor;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( Entry, id, entry1, entry2, useFactor, factor)

template<typename It>
struct testParser : qi::grammar<It, Entry()>
{
   testParser : testParser::base_type(start)
   {
     using namespace qi;
     id_ %= lit("id=") >> int_ ;
     entry1_ %= lit("entry1=") >> char_('[') >> +(char_ -char_(']') % ',') >> char_(']');
     entry2_ %= lit("entry1=") >> char_('[') >> +(char_ -char_(']') % ',') >> char_(']');
    factor %= lit("factor=") >> char_('[') >> int_ >> char_(',') >> int_ >> char_(']');

  start = id >> ';' >> entry1 >> ';' >> entry2 >> (( ';' >> factor[ phx::bind(&Entry::useFactor,_1) = true;] ) >> '!') | '!';

   qi::rule<It, Entry()> start;
   qi::rule<It, int()> id;
   qi::rule<It, std::vector<std::string>()> entry1_, entry2_;
   qi::rule<It, std::pair<int,int>()> factor;
}
};
```

Im getting extreme large compile error messages. I think its because of the entry1 and entry2 rule ( vector of string insertion )

Comment: can you please start posting valid code? There's really no sense in crippling the samples. You can copy/paste. See http://sscce.org. For now: https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might have witnessed in the livestream, I've incrementally fixed up the grammar.

There were quite a number of "are-you-drunk" moments in there, so I'm not sure I'll be able to capture the essential steps in prose here. By all means, have *[a look at the recorded stream¹](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/fixing-up-a-spirit-grammar/)*.

Some substantial notes (ignoring random typos and clearly confused code):

- use `attr(v)`  to simply expose an attribute (as, in this case `attr(true)`)
- use `lit('c')`, `lit("abc")` or just `'c'` and `"abc"` to *match* literal character (strings) ***without*** capturing their content
- use `%=` only in the presence of a semantic action
- the semantic runs *after* it's subject parser succeeded (and only *iff* it succeeded).

  Therefore even if you should/should have set the `useFactor` member from within a semantic action, it would only have run iff the `factor` part was present (and indeterminate values would be left otherwise).
- formatting is important.
- debugging is important.

Optionally:

- using `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG*` to debug rules
- using `as_vector` to hack a quick way to print the results
- I've shown the technique to use [*inherited arguments*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.qi.reference.parser_concepts.nonterminal.attributes) so you can reuse the `entry` rule for `entry1` and `entry2`

Not shown:

- use a skipper for whitespace insensitivity
- use `no_case` for ... case insensitivity
- with a skipper: beware of `lexeme` to avoid matching the keywords across skipped input characters

The working code, as a ***[SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)***:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a7788499204278b)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace std {
    template <typename T>
    static ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, vector<T> const& v) {
        os << "vector{ ";
        for(auto& e : v)
            os << "'" << e << "', ";
        return os << "}";
    }
    template <typename T, typename U>
    static ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, pair<T,U> const& p) {
        return os << "pair{ '" << p.first << "', '" << p.second << "' }";
    }
}

#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

struct Entry
{
    uint32_t id;
    std::vector<std::string> entry1;
    std::vector<std::string> entry2;

    bool useFactor;
    std::pair<int, int> factor;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Entry, id, entry1, entry2, useFactor, factor)

template<typename It>
struct testParser : qi::grammar<It, Entry()>
{
    testParser() : testParser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        id      = "id=" >> int_;
        entry   = lit(_r1) >> ('[' >> +~char_("],") % ',' >> ']');
        factor  = "factor=" >> ('[' >> int_ >> ',' >> int_ >> ']');

        start = 
                id                >> ';' 
             >> entry(+"entry1=") >> ';' 
             >> entry(+"entry2=") >> ';' 
             >> attr(true)  
             >> (factor | attr(std::pair<int,int>{1,1}))
             >> '!';

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(entry)(id)(factor))
#if 0
#endif
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, Entry()>                               start;
    qi::rule<It, int()>                                 id;
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<std::string>(std::string)> entry;
    qi::rule<It, std::pair<int,int>()>                  factor;
};

int main() {
    std::string const input = "id=1;entry1=[A,B,D];entry2=[bla,blubb];factor=[1,5]!";
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    testParser<It> g;
    It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

    Entry entry;
    bool ok = qi::parse(f, l, g, entry);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(entry) << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
<start>
<try>id=1;entry1=[A,B,D];</try>
<id>
    <try>id=1;entry1=[A,B,D];</try>
    <success>;entry1=[A,B,D];entr</success>
    <attributes>[1]</attributes>
</id>
<entry>
    <try>entry1=[A,B,D];entry</try>
    <success>;entry2=[bla,blubb];</success>
    <attributes>[[[A], [B], [D]], [e, n, t, r, y, 1, =]]</attributes>
</entry>
<entry>
    <try>entry2=[bla,blubb];f</try>
    <success>;factor=[1,5]!</success>
    <attributes>[[[b, l, a], [b, l, u, b, b]], [e, n, t, r, y, 2, =]]</attributes>
</entry>
<factor>
    <try>factor=[1,5]!</try>
    <success>!</success>
    <attributes>[[1, 5]]</attributes>
</factor>
<success></success>
<attributes>[[1, [[A], [B], [D]], [[b, l, a], [b, l, u, b, b]], 1, [1, 5]]]</attributes>
</start>
Parsed: (1 vector{ 'A', 'B', 'D', } vector{ 'bla', 'blubb', } true pair{ '1', '5' })
```

---

¹ (I missed the first part where I was fixing headers, balancing brackets and adding parens to constructors etc... o.O).

Comment: The [recorded stream](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/fixing-up-a-spirit-grammar/) is here. ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: Added a (non-exhaustive) list of the things fixed.